# "ALTER TABLE" to add a database column with Pony ORM

Tags: python, mysql, orm, ponyorm

I try to update an SQL database using Pony ORM, but I didn't found how to ALTER an SQL table to add a column.

What i want to do is:

```
ALTER TABLE USER ADD COLUMN sex char(1);
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use migration tool from [orm-migrations](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/tree/orm-migrations/pony/migrate) branch. It is not officially released yet.

Alternatively, if the database does not contains useful data yet, you can drop all tables and re-create them from scratch:

```
db.drop_all_tables(with_all_data=True)
db.create_tables()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Do you know when orm-migrations will be released ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a work-around to this issue that requires using SQL directly, if that's okay with you. Basically, you can add the column with the `ALTER TABLE` command, then modify your Pony entity class and it should load okay after that.

I don't know if this method works beyond this very basic example, or if this will break something further down the line. Maybe someone who knows more about it can comment on it.

Anyway, here is an MWE of the process.

```python
ponymwe.py
-----------
from pony import orm

db = orm.Database()

class Person(db.Entity):
    name = orm.Required(str)
    #age = orm.Required(int) # <-- this is the column we want to add

db.bind(provider='sqlite', filename='./tmp.sqlite', create_db=True)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

@orm.db_session
def init_populate():
    Person(name='nic cage')

@orm.db_session
def showall():
    orm.show(Person)        # see the schema
    Person.select().show()  # see the entries
```

Run `init_populate()` to put an entry in the db.
Then run the following `update_schema.py` to add the `age` column to your db:

```python
update_schema.py
----------------
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('./tmp.sqlite')
con.execute('ALTER TABLE person ADD COLUMN age INTEGER')
con.execute('UPDATE person SET age=? WHERE name=?', (57, 'nic cage'))
con.commit()
```

Now go back to `ponymwe.py` and uncomment `age = orm.Required(int)`, and run `showall()` to see that the schema and entries have indeed been updated:

```python
# output should be:
class Person(Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(str)
    age = Required(int)
id|name    |age
--+--------+---
1 |nic cage|57
```